# NHibernate and passing direct SQL

Tags: nhibernate, ms-access

I am building c# application that deals with a legacy database based on MSAccess.
There is a table that has a GUID type (Numeric defined as Replication ID).
I tried with many options to map a .NET poco to that table, with not success.
All what I want is to insert into a table.
so, I thought I will just pass a straight sql statement.
I tried this statement, and it worked fine if I run it from within MSACESS sql

```
insert into message (PK_ID, To) values ({guid {a033df0a-2e0c-4085-a022-e60767e402a4}}, 'myemail@yahoo.com')
```

But when I run it from c# using NHibernate's CreateQuery.ExecuteUpdate()

I will get the following error

HQL: insert into message (PK_ID, To) values ({guid {a033df0a-2e0c-4085-a022-e60767e402a4}}, 'myemail@yahoo.com')

line 1:41 no viable alternative at character '{'
line 1:44 no viable alternative at character '{'

And the exception is from ANTLR

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CreateQuery` creates a NHibernate query which expects HQL syntax and `{guid {a033df0a-2e0c-4085-a022-e60767e402a4}}` is not valid HQL. If you want to execute a raw SQL query you need to use `CreateSQLQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Chris
I lost few hours, just because I used the wrong method.
stupid me, and I was wondering why HQL is involved in the error.

But Anyway, while I was struggling, I found a solution to save the guid without direct SQL

The solution is :

1. in the POCO object, make the column that is GUID a string
2. and make the value of the column to be equal to `{guid {05E2C49C-D426-6055-0000-000000008E0D}}`

and just map it normally.
It worked.
I want to clarify, that I am facing only problem with MSAccess.
Before I used GUID a lot with SQL Server with NHibernate with no issues at all.